# list item marker vertically aligned

Tags: html, css

I have a list like so:

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1
    <hr>rest of text</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

- item 1

  ---

  rest of text
- item 2

my problem is the positioning of first item marker which would locate at the
beginning of the first line.
I want it to be aligned vertically according to the entire height that the item occupies

Comment: @diyarazhir A picture of what you want to achieve would go a long way to making it clearer.

Comment: As your question sits, it is very unclear, as you state you have a vertical alignment issue but are unclear as to what. The code is rendering exactly as expected. So I'd suggest updating it with more details (perhaps a markup image) before it gets closed.

Comment: He wants the bullet point of the first li item centered vertically in front of the item. This is achieved by the answer to the question posted as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the work of Paulie-D in [Vertical align custom bullets to the middle of the list content](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/mgOEjv), if you use `display: flex` for `<li>`:

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

li::before {
    content: "•";
    width: 1.2rem;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div>
            item 1
            <hr>rest of text
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>item 2</li>
</ul>
```

A width-cropped screen-grab of the relevant rendering:

[image: Image of render]

`(Pretend code required here because of the link to codepen)`

Answer (score 0):

This certainly is not the most dynamic approach, but by nesting the content within your list items and then positioning them you will be able to align your text to the bullet (instead of the bullet to your text).  Then you will need to change the height of your affected `<li>` to account for the space created:

```css
.list1 {
  height: 40px;
}

.containment {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list1">
    <div class="containment">
      item 1
      <hr/> rest of text
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="list2">
    item 2
  </li>
</ul>
```